# JavaScript - JQuery - focus() method - infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a functionality that allows keyboard tabbing between two buttons (CodePen below). More specifically I would like the user to be able to tab onto "button1" and on tab, jump to "button2" and then on tab jump back to button 1.

My solution is to put an event listener on "button1" and listen for a tab keyboard event. When that is triggered, use JQuery's focus() method to shift focus to "button2". On "button2" there is an identical listener that listens for tab event and shift focus back to "button1".

The problem is that when I tab onto "button1", the listener records focus and tab event and shift focus onto "button2" which in turn records focus and tab event and shift it back to "button1" again, creating an infinite loop.

Could I please get suggestions in how to solve this problem?

The real world application of this would be to restrict tabbing within a specific module or section of a page.

Thanks!
Steve

https://codepen.io/steveliu7/pen/WOoMJY

```
var $button1 = $('.b1');
var $button2 = $('.b2');

var checkButton = function(event) {
 if ($button1.is(':focus') && event.which === 9){
  console.log($(this))
  $('.b2').focus();
   return;
 };

 if ($button2.is(':focus') && event.which === 9){
  console.log($(this))
  $('.b1').focus();
   return;
 };
}

$('button').on('keydown', checkButton);
```

Comment: Maybe you could set a boolean before calling focus(), and don't run the event for the other button if it's set?

Comment: You are using the wrong events. You want to capture keydown or keypress. Check the event handler for the keycode, if it is the tab key, then use the focus.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I have updated the code. Problem is still that when the I trigger the event on "button1", the event on "button2"  get triggered as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to restrict tab navigation between two buttons.

Note that it won't restrict screenreaders navigation to those two buttons.

You have to consider TAB navigation but also SHIFT+TAB navigation

On a purely technical point of view `event.preventDefault()` is what your are searching for:

```
var checkButton = function(event) {
  if (event.which === 9) {
    if ($button1.is(':focus')) {
      $button2.focus();
      event.preventDefault();
    } else if ($button2.is(':focus')){
      $button1.focus();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do can be achieved much easier with the `tabindex` property in HTML. If you want to restrict tabbing to certain elements only, you can set `tabindex="-1"` for those elements that you do not want focused.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp